# Setting up a simple AR View in Android Studio with ARCore (Kotlin)

Tags: android, kotlin, arcore, arview

I have major problems setting up a simple ARView with ARCore. I looked in many forums, even Googles official ARCore website, how to set Up ARCore. The Problem isnt adding the Dependencies in Gradle or the permissions in the Android manifest, but rather how I make use of the API. I searched for really really basic knowledge, but all the Forums start with already set up Projects and then dive deeper into some more specific stuff, like raycasting or object placement. For the start I would be very happy if I knew how to setup a ARCore Session and link it to a View in the layout.xml in Order to just see the Camera Vision and work on from there.

I know this seems like a very basic question, but everything I find in forums is way too specific and I cant find a basic tutorial.

Thanks in advance!!!

I tried to setup a ARCore session. I requested Camera permission etc.. I have no clue how to get the View linked to the AR Session in order to have a "Camera Vision".